# Unrecognised Service for existing, working service - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, server, 18.04, services

I'm trying to load a script on boot in Ubuntu Server 18.04.
My `.service` script is installed in `/etc/systemd/system`, and I can run:

```
service my-service start
```

and:

```
service my-service stop
```

But when I try to run at boot (which according to the web I should do) with:

```
 service my-service enable
```

the system responds with:

```
 my-service: unrecognised service
```

Searching the web only tells me how to do it in older versions of Ubuntu which do not apply to 18.04 and I am unable to determine the correct terminology to find the answer.

The script:

```bsh
# filename: /etc/systemd/system/my-service.service
[Unit]
Description=My Service
After=network.target
After=mysqld.service

[Service]
User=the-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/the-user/path-to-script
ExecStart=/home/the-user/path-to-script/start.sh
SuccessExitStatus=0
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My question is: What am I doing wrong? How can I start this service on boot?

Comment: Have you tried using the real command, systemctl enable my-service?

Comment: I think I must be dyslexic. I tried that command over an over again, because most articles refer to that. But reading my command history I used servicectl instead of systemctl. There's 3 days I'll never get back... THANKS.

Comment: Great, I've added an answer with some extra info

Comment: I noticed, thank you! Question answered and improved upon :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the real command, which for `systemd` would be:

`sudo systemctl enable my-service`

For reference, you do not have to use the main system directory for the unit file if you want it to run for a normal user, e.g. your own. You can create it in a directory such as:

`~/.config/systemd/user/`

Then you can do:

`systemctl --user enable my-service`

This avoids the need for `sudo`

As you have noted in your comment, when running per-user instances of `systemd` the `User` directive should be absent

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Even better! But just a side note: when using the second option (avoiding sudo), the line "User=the-user" should be removed from the service file, to prevent "Failed to determine supplementary groups: Operation not permitted" error.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** 
In other instances that you get the same error:
The `service` command puts the *object* first !

```
service foo start
```

The *`systemctl`* command does the opposite:

```
systemctl start foo
```

Also, in service, you cannot add ".service", while you can if you use systemctl.